# using :before (or :after) or table tr's

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the effect of buttons sitting outside of the table that are in line with the table rows they effect. To do this, I am trying to use the pseudo elements. I can achieve this easily if I use the :after on the table row, however if i use before, it treats the pseudo element as a new td in the table row and pushes everything over one td, making the table un-aligned.

```
<table class="saInstrcutionTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="saLevel">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="level1"></td>
            <td>Level 1 Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="moveTableLevel">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>1.01</td>
            <td>A.Truck, B.Car, C. House</td>
            <td>Say look at that, turn head and point</td>
            <td>CLorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="moveTableLevel">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>1.02</td>
            <td>A.Truck, B.Car, C. House</td>
            <td>Say look at that, turn head and point</td>
            <td>CLorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="moveTableLevel">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>1.03</td>
            <td>A.Truck, B.Car, C. House</td>
            <td>Say look at that, turn head and point</td>
            <td>CLorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="moveTableLevel">
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>1.04</td>
            <td>A.Truck, B.Car, C. House</td>
            <td>Say look at that, turn head and point</td>
            <td>CLorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using the moveTableLevel class to add the item to add the buttons attached to the table row

```
.moveTableLevel:before
position: relative
content: 'up'
```

If i use :after the desired effect works fine, however I do not want the buttons on the right side of the table. Is there a way to achieve this (possibly using the pseudo elements)?  :before seems to want to add a whole new td. Thanks!

edit: fiddle here for live example http://jsfiddle.net/9mLd6v9L/

Comment: You are indeed using pseudo-elements.

Comment: Both :before and :after on a table row will cause their contents to be wrapped in a table-cell, it's just that the :after won't cause the misalignment because it's at the end. You can't stop that happening, so just allow for it by making sure that every row has some sort of :before pseudo-element.

Comment: Alternatively you could put your generated content in the first cell of the row with `.moveTableLevel td:first-child::before`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem (almost exactly the same, actually). What I ended up doing was using the `:after` psuedo element, but moving it to where I wanted it with `position: absolute` and setting a `left: 0` style.

So I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mLd6v9L/2/) with this, and added a padding to the left side of the whole table (so you can see the content)

```
.moveTableLevel:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'up';
    left: 5px;
}
```

It kind of goes against my beliefs of using absolute positioning (which I think should be as little as possible), but it was the only way I could fix it.  Hopefully this will work for you too.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. I found that I can simply re-adjust things by pushing the header as well:

```
table thead tr::before {
    content: "";
}
```