# Inserting an icon on the left of table cell

Tags: css

I've a simple table cell and trying to add an icon on the left of each th cell using ::before. My codepen here: https://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/RwQXKGG

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ROW 1<th>
    <td>ROW 1 DATA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}

table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:80%;
}

tr
{
  background-color:rgb(255,255,255,0.2);
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}


th::before
{
    content: '';
  background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/Vr6wPqQ2/car1.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
    left:0px;
  top:0px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

The icon shows up but looks cut-off though. I've also tried the float:left method but it doesn't work. I could add a narrow column on the left of the table and put the icon there, but in the real case (this codepen is only to isolate the issue), it's a Wordpress site and I'm trying to use CSS to customize the plugin's look, without going into the plugin file to adjust the CSS/PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using :before (or :after) or table tr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430114/using-before-or-after-or-table-trs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue with background size. you have used icon as background image so you have to put size of background as well. so the solution would be `background-size: contain;`

```
th::before
{
  content: '';
  background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/Vr6wPqQ2/car1.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-size: contain; /*New added*/
}
```